# Nest JS app is not Starting on my machine

Tags: javascript, next.js

I Have been having this issue on starting Next JS app on my machine it keep given this  error. please i need advice on what to do
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\lenovo\property_rent.next\BUILD_ID'] {   errno: -4058,   code: 'ENOENT',   syscall: 'open',   path: 'C:\Users\lenovo\property_rent\.next\BUILD_ID' }

I try to run build on the app but still not working

Comment: Is there a stacktrace that you can paste? And the relevant piece of code that's trying to open this file?